# Two volume levels, if headphones are in and out

Tags: xubuntu, volume-control

I'm using XFCE on xubuntu.  But there is a volume control on the main taskbar thing.

On windows 7, when I plug in headphones, I have a separate set level of the volume.  Generally I leave the non-headphone muted, and the headphone-in one at an appropriate level.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is this:

- Go to `Accessories` → `Terminal Emulator`
- Type *alsamixer*

Something that resembles the Windows 7 menu should appear.

Just use the cursor to navigate and *m* to mute or un-mute.

Comment: This has no separate controls or settings for headphone usage